# gdalwarp messing up GSD

Tags: transform, gdal, geo

I downloaded the DHM25 raster: https://www.swisstopo.admin.ch/en/geodata/height/dhm25.html

It comes with a dhm25_grid_raster.asc file that I would like to warp to EPSG:4326 (WGS84). That site lists the coordinate reference as "LV03 LN02" and the documentation that comes with the data lists it as "CH1903" which I believe is either EPSG:21781 or EPSG:5728.

Question 1: Does anyone know if it should be EPSG:21781 or EPSG:5728?

When I run the following code, it seems to work converting it to a .tif:

```
drv = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
ds_in = gdal.Open('dhm25_grid_raster.asc')
ds_out = drv.CreateCopy('dhm25_grid_raster.tif', ds_in)
srs = osr.SpatialReference()
srs.ImportFromEPSG(21781) #5728?
ds_out.SetProjection(srs.ExportToWkt())
ds_in = None
ds_out = None
```

I can print the GSD and it looks correct:

```
src = gdal.Open('dhm25_grid_raster.tif')
_, xres, _, _, _, yres  = src.GetGeoTransform()
print(xres, yres)
# 25.0 -25.0
```

Question 2: Is the `yres` supposed to be a negative value?

The negative value threw me so I tried using gdalwarp to convert the .asc straight to WGS84:

```
gdalwarp -s_srs EPSG:21781 -t_srs EPSG:4326 -dstnodata -32767.0 -r cubic -ot Int16 -of GTiff C:/somewhere/dhm25_grid_raster.asc C:/somewhere/warp25.tif
```

The resulting .tif looks to be correct. However when I load it and print the GSD, I get this:

```
src = gdal.Open('warp25.tif')
_, xres, _, _, _, yres  = src.GetGeoTransform()
print(xres, yres)
# 0.0003034045846788908 -0.0003034045846788908 !!!!
```

I tried setting the `-tr 25.0 -25.0` flag but got the error:

```
ERROR 1: Attempt to create 0x0 dataset is illegal,sizes must be larger than zero.
```

I tried setting the `-tr 25.0 25.0` flag but got the same error.

Question 3: How do I get gdalwarp to preserve the 25m GSD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I think LN02 is only the datum, related to the vertical dimension. It's needed (perhaps) to correctly interpret what the height values actually mean, how is 0.0 meters defined etc.
   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_datum

   The geospatial projection seems to be EPSG:21781 indeed.
2. The negative y-value is fine, it just means that the y-coordinate decreases when moving down ("~south") from the top. This is similar to EPSG:4326 for example, which starts with 90° at the North Pole, and **decreases** to -90°.
3. You change the projection, which also changes the spatial unit from meters to degrees. So the value of ~0.0003 is the degree equivalent of 25 meters. If you don't set it, gdalwarp will automatically create this best approximation, but it's also possible to set it yourself.

   It's sometimes nice for example to have more rounded values for the bounding box and resolution. It can avoid errors when typing it manually, or avoid floating point precision issues etc. But that completely depends on the use case of course.

If I assign `EPSG:21781` in QGIS and compare it with Google Maps (which isn't necessarily perfectly located), at least the ballpark location looks reasonable to me.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your great explanations! If that dem is using a compound horizontal+vertical datum (EPSG:21781 horizontal and EPSG:5728 vertical), would it make the most sense to specify that with: `gdalwarp -s_srs EPSG:21781+5728 -t_srs EPSG:4326 ... etc`? What happens if I don't specify a vertical datum in the `-t_srs EPSG:4326`?

Comment: Reprojecting to another spatial projection wont change the height values in the DEM, so they remain LN02. It depends on what your doing with the DEM whether it matters much. Especially combining it with elevations using another datum is where you would want to convert/unify the values. For example ranking mountain tops between different countries using their own local DEM with a local datum. 

Or it might come into play for special applications like orthorectification of aerial/satellite imagery etc.

Comment: Here's for example an article about the difference between LN02 and the newer LHN095. It's not even a single offset, but the difference is location dependent. 
https://web.archive.org/web/20100607014938/http://www.swisstopo.admin.ch/internet/swisstopo/en/home/topics/survey/networks/lhn95.html

Comment: I intend to combine it with other SRTM, which I believe has the vertical datum EPSG:5773. What would the gdalwarp command look like to convert the height values? `gdalwarp -s_srs EPSG:21781+5728 -t_srs EPSG:4326+5773 ... etc` or would height correction involve a second separate gdalwarp?

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest, it would require a vertical datum shift I think. The swiss topo does provide a model, but that's not with respect to LN02 it seems. 
https://www.swisstopo.admin.ch/en/knowledge-facts/surveying-geodesy/geoid.html

That model is also incorporated into PROJ (and GDAL might be able to use it), so perhaps those tools could help you out. Asking a new question specifically about the vertical shift might give you the best result from some actual experts on these height models, the GIS stackexchange or the GDAL/PROJ mailinglist might be a better place than StackOverflow.